# System malfunctioning after uninstalling python3

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I use Parrot OS v4.7, there was an issue with Pyinstaller (*Dependencies problem but all the dependencies were fulfilled/installed*)  so I googled and tried to uninstall and reinstall Python3.

I ran

```
apt-get remove python3
```

but it started removing other packages as well,
now the computer is not functioning normally.

It deleted:

- Mate-interface
- bluefish

screenshot is not working, it says:

```
Failed to execute child process “mate-screenshot” (No   such file or directory))
```

- dashboard
- and many other packages, the system is not functioning as it was before.

and now when I try to reinstall Python3 to get them back, error occurs.
It gives the following output while running

When i run

```
apt-get install python3
```

or

```
apt-get install --reinstall python3
```

i get:

```
(Reading database ... 401001 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3_3.7.5-3_amd64.deb ...
running python pre-rtupdate hooks for python3.7...
Unpacking python3 (3.7.5-3) over (3.7.5-3) ...
Setting up python3 (3.7.5-3) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.7...
running python post-rtupdate hooks for python3.7...
Setting up python3-lib2to3 (3.8.0-1) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3.8'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 0
  user site = 1
  import site = 0
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3.8'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3.8'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the file
system encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f763db09740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
dpkg: error processing package python3-lib2to3 (--configure):
 installed python3-lib2to3 package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distutils:
 python3-distutils depends on python3-lib2to3 (>= 3.6.4); however:
  Package python3-lib2to3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distutils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-all:
 python3-all depends on python3-distutils (>= 3.7.5-1~); however:
  Package python3-distutils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-all (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dev:
 python3-dev depends on python3-distutils (>= 3.7.5-1~); however:
  Package python3-distutils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.0-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-lib2to3
 python3-distutils
 python3-all
 python3-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me to reinstall the Python3 and get the deleted packages back such that the computer may work properly.

Mostly it deleted the system packages.

Answer (score 0):

been there done that. You won't get it working unless you are capable of building linux from scratch :)

reinstall is fastest way forward.

Comment: I have the  bootable USB of the same OS, so is it possible to load the broken or missing packages from there...?   
I don't think building linux from scratch is that easy...

Comment: @CHD No, don't rebuild. Simply `apt-get install mate-interface` and other relevant packages, they will reinstall python3. You must live with python...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first to install **pentesting** tools that are uninstalled use this command

```sh
sudo apt-get install parrot-tools-full
```

and also when you uninstall **python3** some editing tools are also uninstalled like **libreoffice** .. the reinstall **mate linux evironment**

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for collaborating with the community. Your answer seems to be good, I would just suggest adding more highlights to the quoted command by adding it to a code block